# Get Number of Weeks that have passed from a certain date to today SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, stored-procedures, sybase, datepart

Im trying to design a table with a column that has the total number of weeks that have passed from a static, hardcoded date, until today. For example, if the today is June 27, 2014, I want to find how many weeks have passed since May 31st, 2012; the program here would return 108 weeks.

Most results I have found have the week counter roll over at each new year, I would like to find something that keeps counting past 52.

Im using a SYBASE ASE db if that is any help.

Comment: just subtract the two days and divide the result by 7. you will get your number of weeks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use DATEDIFF function:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(wk, '2012-08-20', '2014-06-27');
```

As described [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36271.1550/html/blocks/X47295.htm) or [here](http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/datediff):